# Cross object reference for trigger Opportunity -> user

Tags: apex, opportunity, custom-field, user

I am trying to access a custom field on User object in my trigger on Opportunity.
If the Opportunity Owner has this custom field checked on his user page i need a custom field on Opportunity populated.

How would i go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this in a bulkified way, you need to use sets and maps.

```
public static void setOpportunityValues(List<Opportunity> newRecords)
{
    Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Opportunity record : newRecords)
        ownerIds.add(record.OwnerId);
    Map<Id, User> owners = new Map<Id, User>([
        SELECT My_Checkbox__c FROM User
        WHERE Id IN :ownerIds
    ]);
    for (Opportunity record : newRecords)
    {
        User owner = owners.get(record.OwnerId);
        if (owner.My_Checkbox__c)
            // do stuff
    }
}
```